# Change admin product "virtual" checkbox field label name in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, backend

I would like in admin product pages to change the checkbox field label name for "Virtual" to "Service" like shown in this screenshot:

[image: service instead virtual]

Any help or track will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry , but what do you mean exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

The following code will change the label name for "Virtual" checkbox, in admin product pages:

```
add_filter( 'product_type_options', 'product_type_options_label_change', 10, 3 );
function product_type_options_label_change( $args ) {
    $args['virtual']['label'] = __("Service", "woocommerce");

    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

[image]